# Formatting SQL Server date causes datatype issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I tried this SQL query

```
select format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')
```

I get this result:

```
2016-07-01 23:19:16.573
```

But when I try this, it throws an error:

```
select format('2016-06-28T23:44:23.7573244Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

Error:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

Why is this happening? I think both are almost similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first convert the string to a `DATETIME` object before you call `FORMAT`:

```
FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-28T23:44:23.757Z', 127), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

If you wanted to use your original input, you might have to `STUFF` away the extra time data beyond millisecond precision:

```
FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,
               STUFF('2016-06-28T23:44:23.7573244Z', 24, 4, ''),
               127), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

Comment: I tried select FORMAT(CONVERT(varchar, '2016-06-28T23:44:23.757Z', 127), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') and see Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

Comment: Shouldn't varchar be datetime?  I get an exception with varchar but not datetime

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Sorry, I fixed the typo.